# What method is defined to be called if the argument matches multiple method signatures?

Tags: java, specifications

Given code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    doSomething(new ArrayList());
}

public static void doSomething(Collection collection) {
    System.out.println("Collection here!");
}

public static void doSomething(List list) {
    System.out.println("List here!");
}
```

This prints out `List here!` as expected, but is this behaviour defined somewhere in the Java Specifications so I can rely on it, given any Java implementation?

Comment: It calls the most specific method (I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate)

Comment: Yes, it's defined in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).

Comment: Even though the behaviour is well-defined, IMHO you should not rely on it. Either make both overloaded versions do the same thing for the same parameters, or don't use overloading.

Comment: The question isn't "How does it behave", it is more of a "Is this defined behaviour or implementation dependent". @PaulBoddington Not intuitive if you work on a framework and have different method names for the same task with different arguments, but propably the safer approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At compile time most specific method choosen to invoke.

In your case

```
ArrayList > List > Collection
```

Since `ArrayList` is the most specific sub type of `List` and List is the most Specific subtype of `Collection`.

Here is specification on rules for method invokation

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2

Answer (score 0):

There's even more interesting behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Collection myCollection = new ArrayList();
    doSomething(myCollection);
}

public static void doSomething(Collection collection) {
    System.out.println("Collection here!");
}

public static void doSomething(List list) {
    System.out.println("List here!");
}
```

This will print Collection here!

Comment: Does this answer the question? It just seems like an observation about the behavior.

Comment: Isn't this expected behavior ?

Comment: Yes it's expected behaviour. No it doesn't answer the question as others have said that the most specific method is chosen. I thought I'd highlight that it's early bound rather than late bound / polymorphic.

Comment: Doesn't anwsers my question, I know that (atleast) the Oracle Java implementation behaves like this, but I want to know if this is specified, so I can rely on this behaviour independently of the Java Implementation. But thanks for pointing out that additional behaviour.

Comment: Even without looking up the JLS you can be quite sure that the language basics will work consistently across different Java implementations.